# How to use JS to stack double choice

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a form with a dropdown list and 3 radio buttons.
What i want is that when i click SUBMIT, check the two options. 
I think that could be possible with a Javascript IFs but i'm not sure about this. 
Could some one help me?

HTML

```
<body>
<div class ="container glass">
<div class= "center">
<form class = "resize" onSubmit="return checkAnswer();">
<legend>Pais</legend>
<select class = "resize" name="answer" id="answer" placeholder="Pais" required>
<option value="Italia">Italia</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="always" value="always"/>
<label for="always">Acta de Nacimiento</label>
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="never" value="never"/>
<label for="never">Acta de Matrimonio</label>
<input type="radio" name="editList" id="change" value="costChange"/>
<label for="change">Acta de Muerte</label>
<input type="submit" class = "resize" value="SUBMIT" />        
</select>
</form>          
</div>
```

Comment: it's `onSubmit="checkAnswer()"` instead of what you've written

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery, your function will probably look something like this

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    var selectValue = $('#answer').val();
    swtich(selectValue){
        case "Italia":
            //do something
            break;
        case "Argentina":
            //do something else
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Probably better to ask the OP if a jQuery answer is acceptable before assuming they want to include an entire library for something this basic

Comment: OP used the jQuery tag, so it's a safe assumption

Comment: They did? I don't see it.

Comment: But with this function i'm only checking between Italia and Argentina I'm right?

I want to make a double check, first with the dropdown and then with the radio, so i would have 6 diferent outputs.

Comment: you could use a switch statement too if there are more than just the two options (see my edit)